# Exclude some files from Windows system restore

Tags: windows-7, windows, system-restore, windows-7-restore

In my Win7 machine have a local MYSQL database with all its data file under `c:\mysqldata`

If I try a system restore this restores all database files to restore date like a huge rollback. How can I avoid restore of this folder and all its contents and maintain original files?

I tried to add this values:

c:\mysqldata* /s

to these registry keys:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\BackupRestore\FilesNotToBackup
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\BackupRestore\FilesNotToSnapshot
```

But I still have rollbacks when I try to restore Windows. Am I missing something?

**LITTLE UPDATE**

I compared folder contents before and after the restore and seems that windows REMOVES files with extension IBD becase [this is a monitored extensions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378870(v=vs.85).aspx)

Can I avoid this deletion?

Comment: This sounds like a classic example of storing non-essential core OS data that's large or has other backup methods to a separate disk partition than the core "C" drive. If you had a separate partition carved out with your SQL data & told MySQL per configs to store DB data files and such there, you would not need all these special rules to include or exclude something you could have it work in the default and standard manner for the core OS "C" drive for the Windows OS. Maybe not the solution you are looking for but moving forward, consider data backup needs, etc. with file system configuration.

Comment: This is a distribuitable software and unfortunately I cannot ask a separate partition as requirement for installation. Can be more easy to set a key in registry with an installer to avoid this behaviour. Rather I will disable system restore.